# Azure Devops Pipeline ignoring a specific folder

Tags: git, npm, azure-devops, pipeline, release

I created a pipeline to update a test env everytime I commit a change in a branch and everything in the solution folder update, excepts a specific folder. I cant seem to find why.

[image: files in the azure devops]

The whole folder 'SistemaAvaliacao' updates, but the folder 'JS' and its contents do not go to the VM application folder.

Those are npm install files, i moved them from root folder because I am testing multiple versions of a single library.

Please help

---

Edit 1:

Release process, simple as this.

Sorry if i missed important info on this, amateur to azure.

[image: print]

Comment: You need to include what your release process looks like (minimal reproducible example)